# How far in meters from the Sun's center is the Earth-Sun center of mass?

Tags: mass, earth, sun

Like any set of massive objects separated by distance, the Earth and Sun have a center of mass. How far in meters from the Sun's center is the Earth-Sun center of mass? Just curious? Also what percent of the Sun's radius is this distance?

Answer (score 3):

On [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_%28astronomy%29), it says 449000 m or 0.000646 of the sun's radius.